# ImageMagick - Add white transparent overlay to image

Tags: image, imagemagick, command-line-interface, mask

I need to take a normal image:

[image]

and add a white, transparent overlay so it looks something like this:

[image]

Don't pay attention to the text on the converted image or the fact that it's a cropped version of the original. I need to simply convert the top to the exact same image, just with this white, transparent overlay. I also need it to be a cli command.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

This is even easier

```
convert house.jpg -fill white -colorize 80%  result.png
```

**Original Answer**

Something like this maybe...

```
convert house.jpg \( +clone -fill white -colorize 80% \) -composite result.png
```

[image]

Comment: That is EXACTLY what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Comment: Actually, it is even easier... hang on a minute!

Comment: I wonder what is this `clone` functionality for? Creating a virtual layer? :)

Comment: @DimitryK It creates a copy (clone) of the original image with the same size, which is then filled with white to 80%.

Comment: Hi I found your solution, thanks. I used it with black instead of white... How can I add white text on it?

Comment: Is there anyway to do this for images in bulk?

Comment: Yes `magick mogrify -fill white -colorize 80% *.jpg` but make a backup first.

Comment: @shutupchigo see above.