# Change the RGB numbers of images using ImageMagick

Tags: image, imagemagick

I am trying to convert images to rgb: (R:242 - G:235 - B: 190), but I can't seem to find the right command for that.  All I found was this command that darkens the image, but when I changed `gray47` to the numbers I want the output was black:

```
   convert \
       input.jpg \
      -channel red   -fx 'r - gray47' \
      -channel green -fx 'g - gray47' \
      -channel blue  -fx 'b - gray47' \
       output.jpg
```

ImageMagick version 6.8.9-9 Q16 x86_64

Or if any other command/script does that for Linux in bulk I am open to try anything else.

I want to batch colorize all images in a folder and subfolders from

[image]

to:

[image]

In ACDsee the colorize works well with these options, but it's slow and doesn't allow subfolders (for thousands of images):
[image]

Comment: What is `(R:242 - G:235 - B:190)` please? I have never seen such a thing. Do you want subtract something from something? Or make a solid colour?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, perhaps I am asking the question wrong, sorry.  I used ACDsee colorize a whole image, and it have me these numbers, like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JBsp.png and it changed the tone of the whole image like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ott1t.png

Comment: Still doesn't make much sense. Are you trying to fix the color temperature?

Comment: Please say in plain English what you want to do. Or give 2-3 input images and show what the corresponding outputs would be. Thank you.

Comment: I added an example image for the input and the output needed.

Comment: I think you maybe want something like this... have a read and try varying the percentage https://stackoverflow.com/a/33525744/2836621

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want a constant color output image in ImageMagick. You can do that by converting your colors to percent.

> R:242 - G:235 - B:190

So

```
R=242/255=94.9%
G=235/255=92.2%
B=190/255=74.5%
```

Then

```
convert input.jpg -fill "srgb(94.9%,92.2%,74.5%)" -colorize 100 output.jpg
```

If on ImageMagick 7, then change `convert` to `magick`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried that but it changed the whole image to a single color.

Comment: I added an example image for the input and the output needed.

Comment: In ACDsee the colorize works well with these options: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JBsp.png it's slow and doesn't allow subfolders.

Comment: Why have you cropped off the name of the ACDsee dialog box and not said what you are actually trying to do? What menu options did you select to get there?

Comment: Sorry @MarkSetchell . Added.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to adjust the whitepoint to make the new white 242, 235, 190.

You can do this by multiplying the channels by 255 / 242, 255 / 235, 255 / 190, or 1.05, 1.09, 1.34. You can use `recolor` for this, eg.:

```
red_scale=1.05
green_scale=1.09
blue_scale=1.34
convert $infile -recolor "$red_scale 0 0 0 $green_scale 0 0 0 $blue_scale" $outfile
```

This is a 3x3 colour recombination matrix -- be careful to get all the 0s in the right place.

You could also consider [libvips](https://www.libvips.org/):

```
vips linear $infile $outfile "$red_scale $green_scale $blue_scale" "0 0 0"
```

It should be faster and use less memory.